# measure on a finite space

Tags: measure-theory

I'm new to measure theory and I don't really have a grasp of what a measure is. so I wanted to ask a seemingly basic question.

Say I have a finite space $A = \{2,4\}$ does this mean that $\mu(A) = 2$ since the size of $A$ is 2.

Comment: You may put whatever weights you want on 2 and 4, even 0, and it will still be a measure. It does not have to be the cardinality measure.

Comment: so a measure is something that we can choose to design so long it respects the definition of a measure?

Comment: That's right in general. Though if it is a probability measure, the weights should sum to $1$

Comment: alright I see thank you very much!